# Can i use ES6 syntax import() function to load image?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I want to use `import()` function to load an image, like this:

```
import("./../assets/Index.png")
    .then(res => {
        console.log("success", res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("err", err));
```

However, the console tells me:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

So I was wondering how I could do that?

### Update

Actually, I run it in a browser environment because I don't want to use `require()` function to load an image.

Comment: *I don't want to use require() function to load an image.* - You don't have to worry about that, there's no `require()` in browsers.

Comment: What is more important: what do you want to do? So far it seems more like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Importing of images in that fashion is a feature supported by some build tools (such as webpack) which allow images to undergo processing at build time.

At run time, that benefit can’t exist. Browsers have not implemented any feature that allows `import` to handle images.